# Is it possible to use SVN for project in multiple directories

Tags: svn

I have two projects `ERP` and `HR` and directory of common modules `Common` that are all sitting into directory structure:

```
D:
  ERP
    src
      ...
  HR
    src
      ...
  Common
    src
      ...
```

So - `ERP` and `HR` project each uses modules from the `Common`, besides `ERP` project uses alos modules from the HR. So - how I can organize repository for `ERP`? Is it possible to add modules to the repository of `ERP` from the directories of `HR` and `Common`?

Or maybe I should place all 3 projects in one large directory. Then - can I create 3 repositories in one directory, i.e. can the same file belong to multiple repositories of SVN?

Comment: Have you tried using the `svn:externals` property ? I recommend you to use it in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend you to add `svn:externals` properties to your *ERP* and *HR* repository folders.
Thanks to these properties, you can:

- keep your repository organization as it is, i.e. with no duplication of shared code
- checkout automatically *Common* folder as a local subfolder of *ERP* (when you checkout *ERP* folder)
- checkout automatically *Common* folder as a local subfolder of *HR* (when you checkout *HR* folder)
- checkout automatically the *HR* folder as a local subfolder of *ERP* (when you checkout *ERP* folder)

For example, when adding the `svn:property` to *HR* folder, you will indicate:

- the name of the local subfolder that will contain the checked-out content of *Common*
- the URL of the *Common* folder in repository
- the revision of *Common* you want to checkout (by default it is the HEAD revision)

Here are links for how to do so:

- [Subversion online doc](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.externals.html)
- [TortoiseSVN online doc (Windows only)](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-externals.html)